# remove ALL duplicate elements from an array

Tags: php, array

I have this code to remove duplicates (all occurrences) from an associative array, does PHP have methods to do this ? Or is there a way to improve the code ?

I looked for array_unique, array_search, array_map, array_reduce...

```
$articles = [
    [
        "id" => 0,
        "title" => "lorem",
        "reference" => "A"
    ],
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "title" => "ipsum",
        "reference" => "B"
    ],
    [
        "id" => 2,
        "title" => "dolor",
        "reference" => "C"
    ],
    [
        "id" => 3,
        "title" => "sit",
        "reference" => "A"
    ]
];

$references = array_column($articles, "reference");
$duplicates = array_values(array_unique(array_diff_assoc($references, array_unique($references))));

foreach($duplicates as $duplicate) {
    foreach($references as $index => $reference) {
        if($duplicate === $reference) {
            unset($articles[$index]);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * $articles = [
 *     [
 *         "id" => 1,
 *         "title" => "ipsum",
 *         "reference" => "B"    
 *     ],
 *     [
 *         "id" => 2,
 *         "title" => "dolor",
 *         "reference" => "C"  
 *     ]
 * ]
 */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task can and should be done with a single loop with no pre-looping variable population and no inefficient `in_array()` calls.  Searching keys in php is always more efficient than searching values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cRU6e))

```
$found = [];
foreach ($articles as $index => ['reference' => $ref]) {
    if (!isset($found[$ref])) {
        $found[$ref] = $index;
    } else {
        unset($articles[$index], $articles[$found[$ref]]);
    }
}
var_export($articles);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'ipsum',
    'reference' => 'B',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'title' => 'dolor',
    'reference' => 'C',
  ),
)
```

I am using array destructuring syntax in my `foreach()` for brevity and because I don't need the other column values.

Finally, it doesn't matter if there are triplicates (or more instances of a `reference` value), the script will handle these in the same fashion. `unset()` will not generate any notices, warnings, or errors if it is given a non-existent element (as a parameter) -- this is why it is safe to unconditionally unset the first found `reference` potentially multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

> #### *is there a way to improve the code ?*

Instead of having two `foreach` loops:

> ```
> foreach($duplicates as $duplicate) {
>     foreach($references as $index => $reference) {
>         if($duplicate === $reference) {
>             unset($articles[$index]);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

It can be simplified using [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/in_array):

```
foreach($references as $index => $reference) {
    if (in_array($reference, $duplicates, true)) {
        unset($articles[$index]);
    }
}
```

While it would still technically have the same complexity (i.e. two loops) it would have one less indentation level, and utilize a built-in function to check if the reference is in the list of duplicate references.

Another solution would be to use [`array_flip()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) to map the last index to references, then loop through the articles and if the index of the current article does not match the index of the last reference (meaning its a duplicate) then remove both the article at the current index as well as the article at the last index that has the reference.

```
$references = array_column($articles, "reference");
$lastIndexes = array_flip($references);

foreach ($articles as $index => $article) {
    if ($lastIndexes[$article['reference']] !== $index) {
        unset($articles[$index], $articles[$lastIndexes[$article['reference']]]);
    }
}
```

Or to make it more readable, the last index can be assigned to a  variable:

```
foreach($articles as $index => $article) {
    $lastIndex = $lastIndexes[$article['reference']];
    if ($lastIndex !== $index) {
        unset($articles[$index], $articles[$lastIndex]);
    }
}
```